# Deleted Mac OS X boot image but can still access files via Boot Camp Windows

Tags: bootcamp, partition, startup

Ok, I know I completely messed up here and it's all my fault, but moving past that -- can anyone help me fix this situation?

I used Boot Camp to install Windows 7 on my MacBook the other day. Then, unsatisfied with the amount of space I'd allocated for this partition, I shrank my OS X partition by a little and tried to expand my Windows partition to include the unallocated space. Of course that didn't work, and I found myself playing around with EaseUs to see if I could make anything happen. Click, click, click, and before I knew it I'd turned my OS X partition into unallocated space.

However, I can still access my home directory (and other system files, which I haven't touched) on the OS X partition via Windows! I have created a manual backup of the files I deem important, in addition to have a pretty recent Time Machine backup. But when I try to have the Boot Camp util restart the computer in OS X, it says "Could not locate the Mac OS X boot volume". And when I restart Windows and hold down the alt key so I can choose my startup disk manually, the only startup disk that is found is Windows.

Can anyone please help me understand what I did and how I can fix it, preferably without having to erase my Windows partition and do everything all over again?

Comment: I am considering just doing a fresh install of OS X over the unallocated space, as I have all of my important files secure. I just don't relish the thought of reacquiring all those applications...

Comment: It sounds like you hosed your partition table in such a way that it can no longer boot. It's not that hard to imagine that Windows might still be able to see into the files while the volume itself is no longer bootable. The best solution is to patch up your partition table, but I'm sure someone more intelligent than I could probably find a way to patch it up in place.